# Determining a PDF from its moments

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-problem

I have a probability density function, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. I can calculate moments of $f$ easily, namely, I can calculate $\int\int x^ay^bf_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ over the range of $X$ and $Y$, for any particular $a$ and $b$ I like.

If I calculate first and second moments, I could approximate $f$ with a gaussian. Suppose I calculated the third and/or fourth moments too. What might I approximate $f$ by, taking into account these extra moments?

[NB: if it helps, I know that $(X,Y)$ are bound within a triangle (say, $X\geq 0$, $Y\geq 0$, $X+Y\leq 1$, but it's up to me). I also expect that $f$ has the form of an algebraic function of $x$ and $y$, but I'm happy to ignore this]

Comment: Calculate the skewness and excess kurtoses and  then depending on the results choose likely distributions. For instance if skewness=0, or at least more or less zero,  then this eliminates many possibilities.

Comment: You may find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435598/determining-a-pdf-from-its-moments) useful

Comment: @caverac did you just link back to my own question?

Comment: :) Sorry, for some reason I copied the wrong [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353490/deducing-a-probability-distribution-from-its-moment-generating-function)

Comment: This looks like a [two-dimensional moment problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.4821).